# Which label is better USP or "About me"?

Tags: usability, labels

Which label is better USP or some thing else?

USP(unique selling proposition) is a marketing concept that was first proposed as a theory to understand a pattern among successful advertising campaigns.

[image]

Comment: In what context are you using this? Is the audience marketing folks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unique Selling Point (USP)" is **marketing** jargon usually applied to startups, whereas "about me" is usually used for user **profiles**.  So you need to choose which one based on the context.

On a side note, acronyms are only useful on their own when you can be reasonably sure that your audience will know what it stands for.  if there is any doubt, use the full term and include the acronym for those that only know it as the acronym.  I would use:

> Edit my Unique Selling Point (USP)

Answer (score 0):

You could also say "Enter my Unique Selling Proposition (USP)" when the current USP is empty and "Update my Unique Selling Proposition (USP)" when there already is an USP.